# Org-columns error : The CLOCKSUM property cannot be set with ‘org-entry-put’

Tags: org-mode

I would like to have summed up logged time with org-columns in org-mode. Apparently it works very well down to level 3 headers (i.e. headers with 3 asterisk), but when I try to log clock for level 4 headers I encounter the following error upon entering org-columns:

> The CLOCKSUM property cannot be set with ‘org-entry-put’

I get the same error message when I try to set by hand the property CLOCKSUM for level 4 sub-headers. Please see a working example below. Trying to update the first columnview table with :id global or generating org-columns for Goal 3 will reproduce the error while Goal 1 and Goal 2 are fine (they do not have level 4 sub-headers with logged clocks).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
#+TITLE: Page planning example
#+PROPERTY: Effort_ALL "" 0:05 0:10 0:20 0:30 1:00 2:00 4:00 6:00 8:00
#+PROPERTY: Estimated_days_ALL "" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM(Details) %25TAGS(Context) %7TODO(To Do) %5Effort(Estimate){:} %6CLOCKSUM{:} %10Budget_day(Daily budget){:} %10Estimated_days(Estimated Days){est+}


#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 2 :id global :maxlevel 2

#+END

* Goal 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BUDGET_DAY: 6:00
  :ID: goal_1
  :END:

  #+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 3 :id goal_1 :Maxlevel 4
  | Details         | Context | To Do | Estimate | CLOCKSUM | Daily budget | Estimated Days |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Goal 1          |         |       |     1:20 |     3:51 |         6:00 |          11-13 |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Project 1       |         |       |     0:20 |     3:51 |         4:00 |            5-7 |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Task 1          |         | TODO  |     0:15 |     1:11 |              |            4-5 |
  | Desired outcome |         |       |          |          |              |                |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | task 2          |         | TODO  |     0:05 |     0:10 |              |            1-2 |
  | Desired outcome |         |       |          |          |              |                |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | task 3          |         | TODO  |          |     2:30 |              |                |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Project 2       |         |       |     1:00 |          |         2:00 |            6-6 |
  |-----------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Task 1          |         | TODO  |     1:00 |          |              |              6 |
  #+END


** Project 1 
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Budget_day+: 4:00
   :END:

*** TODO Task 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Estimated_days: 4-5
   :Effort:   0:15
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-01-27 Mon 19:05]--[2020-01-27 Mon 20:16] =>  1:01
   :END:
**** Desired outcome


*** TODO task 2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   0:05
    :Estimated_days: 1-2
    :END:
    :LOGBOOK:
    CLOCK: [2020-01-28 Tue 14:52]--[2020-01-28 Tue 15:02] =>  0:10
    :END:
**** Desired outcome

*** TODO task 3
    :LOGBOOK:
    CLOCK: [2020-01-28 Tue 12:22]--[2020-01-28 Tue 14:52] =>  2:30
    :END:
    :DEADLINE: <2020-02-02>

*** COMMENT PROJECT META
**** Desired outcome
     Write out outcome of project 1
**** Main folder

** Project 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Budget_day+: 2:00
   :END:

*** COMMENT PROJECT META
**** Desired outcome
     Write out outcome of project 1
**** Main folder


*** TODO Task 1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   1:00
    :Estimated_days: 6
    :END:

** COMMENT Meta

*** Description of the goal
*** Desired outcome
    Write out outcome of the goal


* Goal 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: goal_2
  :END:

  #+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 2 :id goal_2 :maxlevel 3
  | Details   | Context | To Do | Estimate | CLOCKSUM | Daily budget | Estimated Days |
  |-----------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Goal 2    |         |       |    10:20 |     0:01 |         2:49 |           4-14 |
  |-----------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Project 1 |         |       |     8:20 |     0:01 |        00:49 |           2-12 |
  | Task 1    |         | TODO  |    08:15 |     0:01 |              |            1-2 |
  | Task 2    |         | TODO  |     0:05 |          |              |           1-10 |
  |-----------+---------+-------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------|
  | Project 2 |         |       |     2:00 |          |        02:00 |            2-2 |
  | Task 1    |         | TODO  |     2:00 |          |              |              2 |
  #+END


** Project 1 
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Budget_day+: 00:49
   :END:


*** TODO Task 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Estimated_days: 1-2
   :Effort:   08:15
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-01-27 Mon 19:15]--[2020-01-27 Mon 19:16] =>  0:01
   :END:

   Task body
**** Eventual sub-task 1
**** Desired outcome
*** TODO Task 2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   0:05
    :Estimated_days: 1-10
    :END:
    Task body
**** Desired outcome

*** COMMENT PROJECT META
**** Desired outcome
     Write out outcome of project 1
**** Main folder

** Project 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Budget_day+: 02:00
   :END:

*** COMMENT PROJECT META
**** Desired outcome
     Write out outcome of project 1
**** Main folder


*** TODO Task 1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   2:00
    :Estimated_days: 2
    :END:

** COMMENT GOAL META

*** Description of the goal
*** Desired outcome
    Write out outcome of the goal



* Goal 3
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: goal_3
  :END:

  #+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 4 :id goal_3 :maxlevel 4

  #+END

** Project 1 
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Budget_day+: 00:49
   :END:


*** TODO Task 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Estimated_days: 1-2
   :EFFORT:   0:05
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2020-01-26 18:05]--[2020-01-26 Mon 19:16] =>  1:11
   :END:

   Task body

**** TODO Subtask 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Estimated_days: 1-2
   :EFFORT:   0:05
   :END:
     :LOGBOOK:
     CLOCK: [2020-01-28 Tue 15:45]--[2020-01-28 Tue 16:45] =>  1:00
     :END:
```

Comment: A similar error message shows up when trying to insert a property with key equal to `CLOSED` through the `org-entry-put` function (i.e. press <kbd>c-c c-x p</kbd> while the cursor is in an entry). The error message is: `the CLOSED property cannot be set with 'org-entry-put'`.

Comment: The level doesn't seem to relevant.   Changing the level of the subtask gives the same error.  On the other hand adding a new subtask below the given one, no longer gives an error.

Comment: Apparently this bug first cropped up in 2012. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-02/msg00309.html

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. `CLOCKSUM` (and `CLOSED`) are [special properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) and "should not" be used as keys in property drawers. `org-entry-put` actually *forbids* setting them (although of course, "it's just text" so you can do whatever you want  - but if you break the rules, Org mode may not do TRT). The example in the question works (?) for me (in the sense that I get a table and I don't get an error) with Org mode 9.4.4+.

Comment: I take back the last part of my previous comment: the example does *not* work for me either. I get the `CLOCKSUM` property error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the MWE to run, but rewriting `%6CLOCKSUM{:}` as `%6CLOCKSUM` solved the problem for me in a similar situation.

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The description of the special property ‘CLOCKSUM’ contains a hint that "[...] ‘org-clock-sum’ must be run first to compute the values in the current buffer".

Eval'ing (org-clock-sum) in the buffer solved the issue for me.

Comment: Please explain more exactly what needs to be done.  Trying to reproduce the actions did not lead to a solution in my copy of the org file.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do this. How do you evaluate an elisp function within an org buffer?

Comment: `C-c C-c` on each `#+BEGIN: columnview` should be enough: it's supposed to run `org-clock-sum`. You should not have to (and probably should not) call `org-clock-sum` explicitly.